# SQL Java - Simple query to return 10 rows using cursor

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with 70 records and would like to get 10 of these records using a cursor.

The 10 records I have have a `KEY_ROWID`(Primary key) of `2, 3, 15, 23, 35, 50, 51, 60, 61, 64`

What is the SQL to retrieve these records?

Here is what I have so far, but I don't think this will work...

Should I be using the `WHERE` or the `HAVING` clause?

Any help would be great.

```
public Cursor getTopTen() {

    String ids = "2, 3, 15, 23, 35, 50, 51, 60, 61, 64";

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, RECIPE, DESC, PREPTIME,
            COOKTIME, SERVES, CALORIES, FAT, CATEGORY, FAV };

    Cursor myCursor = queryBuilder.query(myDataBase, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
            + "'" + ids + "'", null, null, null, null);

    return myCursor;
}
```

In SQL the java above is:

```
SELECT * FROM myDataBase WHERE KEYROWID = "2, 3, 15, 23, 35, 50, 51, 60, 61, 64".
```

Comment: Use `WHERE`; see [the Wikipedia article on `HAVING`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL should be:

```
SELECT * FROM myDataBase WHERE KEYROWID IN (2, 3, 15, 23, 35, 50, 51, 60, 61, 64)
```

When you want to get all rows where a column value is in a specific list of values you have to use the [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

So your code should be:

```
public Cursor getTopTen() {

    String ids = "2, 3, 15, 23, 35, 50, 51, 60, 61, 64";

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, RECIPE, DESC, PREPTIME,
            COOKTIME, SERVES, CALORIES, FAT, CATEGORY, FAV };

    Cursor myCursor = queryBuilder.query(myDataBase, columns, KEY_ROWID + " IN ("
            + ids + ")", null, null, null, null);

    return myCursor;
}
```

Comment: @Sterlok How do I use this SQL in the java querybuilder?

Comment: You beauty! It works. My first app's ready for the market! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you should be using WHERE clause instead of HAVING clause.